# Failed to install Ubuntu touch on the Nexus 10, what can I do now?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I followed instructions on how to install touch ubuntu on my nexus 10. Everything seemed to be going by just fine until the end.

```
Pushing /home/joshua/Downloads/phablet-flash/135/raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip to /sdcard/autodeploy.zip 
error: device not found 
Error while executing adb push /home/joshua/Downloads/phablet-flash/135/raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip 
Make sure the device is connected and viewable by running 'adb devices' 
Ensure you have a root device, one which running 'adb root' does not return an error
```

I did not root my nexus 10 because the instructions did not say to.... Probably common sense i know, but I over looked it.  now I only get this message. Now it will only show google when booting up and then turns off and I just get a battery sign. I am able to boot up into clockwork recovery but thats about it.

Any help? Is there any way I can sideload? is there anything I can do?

Comment: If you took a backup you should be able to restore it with clockwork

Comment: any feedback on your experience? what's cool? what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***POSSIBLE CONFUSION:***

The command **adb root** simply re-loads the **adb** daemon (as root) on your **desktop PC**. This gives you greater privilege (if needed) to access and control the attached device.

**This is not 'root' for the device. This does NOT affect the device (or its firmware).**

---

***What steps did you complete?***

The (manual) install procedure has only 5 steps: (*eg. for **Nexus 7***)

Image files from: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

**UPDATE:** (2013-Jun-14)

> Current *daily* is now **Saucy (13.10)** (early BETA)
>
> To stay with Raring (13.04), use:
> http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/raring/monthly-06/

**/UPDATE**

> [1.] Check device is attached
>
> **`adb devices`**
>
> ```
> * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5### *
> * daemon started successfully *
> List of devices attached 
> ##############        device
> ```
>
> [2.] Load machine-specific image (eg. for **Nexus 7**/grouper)
>
> **`adb push ~/images/raring-preinstalled-armel+grouper.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip`**
>
> ```
> #### KB/s (######### bytes in ##.###s)
> ```
>
> [3.] Reboot to **Recovery Mode** (and run *autodeploy.zip*)
>
> **`adb reboot recovery`**
>
> [3A.] **(OPTIONAL)** *Repeat previous step:* Reboot to **Recovery Mode**
>
> **Note:** *As the device may not be stable (until after step 4), this places device in a known state while waiting the 2-4 minutes for load to complete.*
>
> **`adb reboot recovery`**
>
> [4.] Load ubuntu-touch (phablet) image (for ANY *supported* device)
>
> **`adb push ~/images/raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip`**
>
> ```
> #### KB/s (######### bytes in ##.###s)
> ```
>
> [5.] Reboot to **Recovery Mode** (and run *autodeploy.zip*)
>
> **`adb reboot recovery`**
>
> The device should reboot to *Ubuntu Touch* (phablet) GUI

Comment: As soon as I downloaded the proper image and pushed it, rebooted, it worked! Thank you so much for taking the time and answering my questions and explaining 'root'. Much appreciated! Now its time to play ;-)