# Stuck on recovery-mode - Galaxy Nexus (phone)

Tags: android, ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I tried to install Ubuntu according to instruction given by https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

however I suck on recovery-mode in the middle of the installation. It seems not [to be] running further so I manually enter "reboot system now" on the phone screen, then I got a error massage in the computer saying that installation is not completed or similar meaning.

Current situation of my phone is, can not boot beyond "Google" [boot] screen; however I still can go into recovery-mode.

please help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Using the manual install method:***

You first need the two **zip** files downloaded, from the link given:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

Download:

- **raring-preinstalled-armel+maguro.zip** (Google Nexus)
- **raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip** (all devices)

Then use the simplified instructions I gave as my answer to:

[Failed to install Ubuntu touch on the Nexus 10, what can I do now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299723/failed-to-install-ubuntu-touch-on-the-nexus-10-what-can-i-do-now)

Step 2 needs: **raring-preinstalled-armel+maguro.zip**

Step 4 needs: **raring-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip**

---

**UPDATE:**

If you are having issues, and have already attempted loading (or have previous daily image), then try reverting to a "fresh install".

Use the automated method:

**`phablet-flash -d maguro -b`**

---

***Otherwise:***

If you can't successfully install **Ubuntu Touch**, first return the device **to a known state**.

*eg. Restore factory Android image (per first link above).*